# Adjusting block height of a parent which contains vertically transformed child

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a simple overflow effect of card over header area with CSS. An issue is that the card's parent block height is not adjusted properly if the card is moved up with the use of a CSS "transform". Same as with the use of "top" property.

Here is a basic markup and styles, as well as [demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/ioi0/jk92fnb2/)

```
<section class="header"></section>
 <section class="wrapper">
   <article class="card"></article>
   <h1>Content to be right under the card</h1>
</section>

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
}
.card {
  width: 80%;
  /* position: relative;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 400px;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  /* top: 200px; */
}
```

As you will see in the demo, an h1 element is placed too low because of the assumed height of an article element. Ideally, it should be placed right under the article element. How is it possible to achieve this without using other types of positioning attributes on those elements.

Comment: CSS transforms not affecting the position of surrounding elements is typically a good thing - however, in this case the solution is almost entirely dependent upon what your eventual goal is for the layout. One quick fix might be to adjust the Y position of the card with `margin-top: -200px;`, although again, I would stress that it's dependent upon your overall goals.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! My eventual goal is to keep the card overlayed over the first section while being able to present sequential content under it. I first started by implementing your solution with margin property, however it will also push up the parent element (wrapper), meaning I can not control background-color and overlay effect.

Comment: So... is my suggestion working for you? EDIT: Ah, understood. This one is tricky - if this were my issue, I would continue working, then post once I was further along - there are simply too many possible solutions to make a suggestion at this point.

Comment: Maybe you are right, a possible workaround would be to use a margin property on a card and place subsequent content outside of the card. But this is only applicable in case one has access to the markup.